# URL Scheme not opening view

Tags: ios

I'm trying to implement a custom URL Scheme where one particular URL (myapp://article) opens the article view. I'm not having any success though.

Normally the app opens the `LoginViewController` as is defined in the Storyboard. For the URL Scheme I'm doing this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation{

    if ([[PocketAPI sharedAPI] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        NSLog(@"Login complete!");
        return YES;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
        NSLog(@"scheme: %@", [url scheme]);
        NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
        NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);

        if ([[url host] isEqualToString: @"article"]) {
            Stream *stream = [[Stream alloc] initWithDictionary:data];

            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

            ArticleViewController *articleViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ArticleViewController"];

            articleViewController.stream = stream;

            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:articleViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
            return YES;
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
```

I keep getting `Warning: Attempt to present <ArticleViewController: 0x79040cb0> on <LoginViewController: 0x7906f8c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the current `rootViewController` (aka `LoginViewController`) is the only controller presented on the screen? It has another view controllers presented on top?

Answer (score 0):

Try showing the window first before instantiating your view controller. Before you instantiate the window the main view controller is indeed not in the view hierarchy (because there is none yet).